# Can delegate change a URL during WKWebView navigation?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, ios13

The `WKWebView` has a `navigationDelegate` property. That delegate can allow or deny navigation actions (eg, the user following a link) by implementing:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
             decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
             decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

Typical implementations look at properties of the `navigationAction` and call `decisionHandler(.cancel)` or `decisionHandler(.allow)`.

I'd like to tell it that for certain URLs it should add certain query parameters. Something like:

```
if navigationAction.request.url.path == "/foo" {
    navigationAction.request.url.query = "x=1&y=2"
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

That code doesn't work because the `request` is not mutable.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could call decisionHandler(.cancel) if the query parameters are not present and then make a new loadRequest passing a new URL with the query parameters.  This will cause the same delegate method to be called again so add some logic to notice that the query parameters are now present so you can call  decisionHandler(.allow)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying it that way and things are working so far.